# Running and stopping a C++ program from a Python script on Raspberry Pi / Linux

Tags: python, c++, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Google Cloud Firestore Database for my project. I'm trying to retrieve data from the database which is a simple variable (1 or 0) using Python.

So if I get a '1' from the database I want to execute a C++ program from a current Python program. And if I get a '0' I want to terminate that running program.

I'm having a few doubts regarding this,

It's pretty straight forward to run a C++ file from python but how 
do I terminate it and how to check if it's not running before trying to terminate it

The following is my python code

```
import firebase_admin
import time
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
n=1
b=None
cred = credentials.Certificate('/Users/vijaypenmetsa/Desktop/key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        a = doc.to_dict()
        b = a["status"]
        check(b)
#b is the variable retrieved from the database
def check(c):
    if c == 1:
        print("Start Driving")
    elif c == 0:
        print("Halt")
doc_ref = db.collection(u'status').document(u'carstatus')
while n>0:
    doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if a process is running or not by using psutil. Here's a link that will certainly help you: https://thispointer.com/python-check-if-a-process-is-running-by-name-and-find-its-process-id-pid/

the final code will be as follows:

```
import psutil

def checkIfProcessRunning(processName):
    '''
    Check if there is any running process that contains the given name processName.
    '''
    #Iterate over the all the running process
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            # Check if process name contains the given name string.
            if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False;



if checkIfProcessRunning('chrome'):
    print('Yes a chrome process was running')
else:
    print('No chrome process was running')
```

In this case I am using the guy's example and so checking if chrome is running but you can check for whatever you want

**You might want to have pip install psutil for you by running the following code on terminal:**

```
pip3 install psutil
```

or

```
pip install psutil
```